# Datagridview Combobox Cell Max Dropdown not working

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox

Somehow it is still showing around more then 10 values when i asked for 3. IS this even the right way?

```
               Dim c3 As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()

c3.HeaderText = "Stripes"
c3.DataSource = BndSrc

c3.Name = "Stripes"

c3.DataPropertyName = "Stripes"
c3.DisplayMember = "Stripes"
c3.ValueMember = "Stripes"

c3.DisplayStyleForCurrentCellOnly = False
c3.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing
c3.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard
c3.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic
c3.maxdrodownitems = 3 
Me.DataGrid.Columns.Add(c3)
```